# return string from html form to flask

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

this question is pretty common question, but just can't get any way around it for a long time...please help if you can figure out where I am going wrong

I have a form returning a string like this:

```
<form id="details" name="details" method="post">
    <input class="myButton" style="margin-top:300px; margin-left:320px; text-align: center;" type="submit" value="Save" onclick="return getstring()">
    </input>
</form>

<script>
function getstring() {
                ....
                ....
                return "abcd";
                }
</script>
```

Now, in my flask code:

```
def process_details():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('page1.html')
    else:
        returned_details = request.form['details']
        print(returned_details)
```

But when I debug this, during the 'POST' request, it enters correctly in process_details function, but it can't populate the returned_details variable. The return string is not a dictionary, any idea how to return in this case to flask?

in other words, I just need a button inside a form which collects the data from the page and submits when pressed(I get that data on onClick). In flask part so that, when I do request.form['details'], i should get that value.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in form in html page.As you want to run the else part of code when we make a POST request but there is no form which is sending us to that code after submitting.So in short add this in your form;

```
<form action="{{ url_for ('process_details') }}">...</form>
```

Comment: I also want to mention that as you said it enters correctly in process_details function, but actually it is not entering the function.Submission of form just refreshes the page which makes you think like that.

Comment: No mate, doesn't work...in other words, I just need a button inside a form which collects the data from the page and submits when pressed. In flask part so that, when I do request.form['details'], i should get that value....

Comment: give the input field a name and then call for request.from.get["input_name"] and the rest is same.And i think you should use the action atribute.